# Accessing a string variable from one method to another which is declared globally is giving null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I am working on a web app;ication based on asp.net with c#,I have two methods specified below.

```
public partial class ClerkReception_CreateRecords : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string patid;   
protected void ddryear_textchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string month = "";
    if (ddrmonth.SelectedItem.Text == "Jan")
    {
        month = "01";

    }
    else if (ddrmonth.SelectedItem.Text == "Feb")
    {
        month = "02";
    }
    else if (ddrmonth.SelectedItem.Text == "Mar")
    {
        month = "03";
    }



    string year;
    year = ddryear.SelectedItem.Text;
    string locid = Session["Location"].ToString();

    patid = locid + month + year;//Ex:AT112013


    myConnection obj = new myConnection();

    //string result = obj.fnDisplayManualRecords(year, month, locid);
    string result = obj.fnDisplayManualRecords1(patid);

    txtlast.Text = result.ToString();
    if (ddrmonth.SelectedItem.Text != null || ddryear.SelectedItem.Text != null)
    {
        txtlast.Visible = true;
        lbllast.Visible = true;
        BtnProceed.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

This is a method used when a item is selected from dropdownlist,where the patid returns the value.

I need to access the same value of patid inside a another method shown below,Hence I declared the patid as global variable so that I can access the value in any method.But its giving null.How to retieve the vale from one method to another method?

```
protected void BtnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string x = patid;//shows null
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1(SUBSTRING(patientid,9,4)) as MaxpatientID  from Patient_Data where PatientID like '"+patid+"%' order by PatientID desc;", cn))
        {
            try
            {

                cn.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //int Patcount;
                    if (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        int Patcount = int.Parse(rdr["MaxpatientID"].ToString());
                        // if(Patcount == 0)


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                // handle errors here
            }

        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global variables are *created / intialized* between postback in asp.net and they do *not* retain the values between postback as http is stateless protocol, you need to use `ViewState` for that. You can read more about `ViewState` and `Stateless protocol` over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619476/strange-behaviour-of-boolean-variable/14619490#14619490).

To set value in `ViewState`

```
ViewState["patid"] =  locid + month + year;//Ex:AT112013;
```

To get value from `ViewState`

```
string patid = ViewState["patid"].ToString();
```

### View State

> View state's purpose in life is simple: it's there to persist state
>   across postbacks. (For an ASP.NET Web page, its state is the property
>   values of the controls that make up its control hierarchy.) This begs
>   the question, "What sort of state needs to be persisted?" To answer
>   that question, let's start by looking at what state doesn't need to be
>   persisted across postbacks. Recall that in the instantiation stage of
>   the page life cycle, the control hierarchy is created and those
>   properties that are specified in the declarative syntax are assigned.
>   Since these declarative properties are automatically reassigned on
>   each postback when the control hierarchy is constructed, there's no
>   need to store these property values in the view state. You can read
>   more about viewstate [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Comment: Can i know how to access the same variable from one page to another page?

Comment: For cross page you need to use Session instead of ViewState, http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of post backs, each post back recreates the page (class) variables, so you need to save it before post back or it will be gone.

Use a cache object, such as `Session` to maintain values between post back and page navigation. `Session` gives you the power to store and retrieve objects across multiple pages in your application, including just one if you are continually posting back to it.

You can use `Session`, like this:

Storing value in `Session`:

```
Session["ValueToKeep"] = "My important information";
```

Retrieving value from `Session`:

```
// Make sure it is in session cache before we try to get it
if(Session["ValueToKeep"] != null)
{
    string valueINeed = Session["ValueToKeep"].ToString();
}
```

> Note: All items stored in `Session` are `Objects` thus the usage of `.ToString()` on the `Session` item. An item is boxed as an object when inserted into `Session`, but must be unboxed (cast) when retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You class level variables are re-created on postback. You will need to persist them somewhere that continues across requests.. such as ViewState, Session, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to interact with two methods / functions / event-function  in side class is just declaring its accessible modifiers to **public** and you can call any object of that class after initialize some value to it.

```
 public void ddryear_textchanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {....}
 public void BtnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {....}
```

create one variable inside class like string x; and initialize it in constrictor `{ x="some text "; }` this is how code works...

Comment: Please use some Post back to save in its variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get the value of global parameter,
one way is to define the parameter as static